# Sails Socket with Angular 5

Tags: angular, socket.io, sails.js

I am developing an application with a sails backend and Angular 5 as the front end app.

I need to use the sails socket feature with the Angular 5 based app. I added a script tag which is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:1337/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
```

But when I run the ng serv and then the console shows this error. Thanks in advance.

[Console Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZSqh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder `js` in your Angular 5 `/src/assets/` directory.

Put the `sails.io.js` file in your Angular 5 `/src/assets/js/` folder.

Now in your `index.html` give path like follow:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/sails.io.js"></script>`

It will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the error I am getting now.
`GET http://localhost:4200/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=0.13.8&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M77VaMw 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Are you using npm package?

Comment: I have actually integrated both sails and Angular 5.